# PyTrends Keeps returning Google Response with error code 400

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-trends

I've been trying to pull Google Trends data for a number of different keywords and have been looping over each keyword using pandas to build each individual payload. However, I keep getting a Google error code of 400 when I try using a particular row of the keyword. This is the code that I have currently:

```
import csv
import time
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

# set gmail credentials and path to extract data
 

# Login to Google. Only need to run this once, the rest of requests will use the same session.
pytrend = TrendReq()
keywordcsv = "nba.csv"
keywords = pd.read_csv(keywordcsv)
print(keywords)
for index, row in keywords.iterrows():
    print("Downloading Keyword #" + str(index))
    temp = str(row[0])
    pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=temp, timeframe="2013-11-24 2018-11-11", geo='US')
    time.sleep(randint(5, 10))
    null_df = pytrend.interest_over_time()
    print(null_df)
    null_df.to_csv(path_or_buf='blah.csv', mode='a', header=0)
```

Comment: *Which* keyword is causing the error??

Comment: whenever I use a variable for a keyword like temp or row[0], it gives me the 400 error. However, if I explicitly put the keyword such as kw_list = ["wizards"] then it works fine. I want to dynamically keep building different payloads based on the csv file.

Comment: Actually, I just checked. When I declare temp = "wizards" and then pass in [temp] into the kw_list, it seems to work. However, whenever I try to do temp = row[0], it doesn't work and returns an empty data frame.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler

Comment: Add `print(row[0])` to your loop and see what it is trying to pass in as a keyword. Also, could you post the result of `print(keywords)`?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler it prints the correct keyword and the result of print(keywords) is 
0      NLST stock
1      NLTX stock
2        NM stock
3      NMAR stock
4       NMB stock
5      NMFC stock

and it lines up with the csv file that is being read in

Answer (score 2):

I had this error. Turns out you the maximum length of keywords to compare is 5.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `kw_list` is maxxed out at 5 words at a time. Not sure why this is - perhaps due to google's rate limiting. You can try to play around with `timeout` & other params but the foolproof way around this is to cap the batch size at 5.